# Highchart graph missing on the left or right when Highcharts is zoomed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It's just like as following pictures.

[image: before zoom]

[image: after zoom,left missed.]

[image: after zoom,right missed.]

the code as following:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec',
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
      ]
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [
          29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,
          29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,
          29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,
          29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,
          29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,
          29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,
          29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

I want to know how to avoid this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set cropThreshold property for more value than the number of points.

```
  series: [{
    cropThreshold: 100,
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, ...]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/asz8y01f/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.cropThreshold

Comment: I known that,Thanks a lot!